# Why does StepVerifier.Step.expectNoEvent not fail?

Tags: project-reactor

When a flux has a `delayElements` operator, the `StepVerifier.Step.expectNoEvent` correctly throws an AssertionError if an event is emitted before the duration.

Consider the following test:

```java
  @Test
  public void testWithDelayElements() {
    StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> Flux.just(1, 2, 3).delayElements(Duration.ofSeconds(1)))
        .expectSubscription()
        .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
        .expectNext(1)
        .thenCancel()
        .verify();
  }
```

which throws

```
expectation failed (expected no event: onNext(1))
java.lang.AssertionError:...
```

However, if the flux doesn't have a `delayElements` operator, then the test passes.

```java
  @Test
  public void testWithoutDelayElements() {
    StepVerifier.withVirtualTime(() -> Flux.just(1, 2, 3))
        .expectSubscription()
        .expectNoEvent(Duration.ofSeconds(2))
        .expectNext(1)
        .thenCancel()
        .verify();
  }
```

I don't understand why this passes?

Edit:
I see there is a similar [GitHub issue](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1913) which seems to explain the blocking behavior of expectNoEvent in [one of the comments](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/issues/1913#issuecomment-545433360). However, that seems to apply when virtual time scheduler is not being used. I am using the virtual time schedular, so the thread should not be blocked, right?

Comment: fyi: adding a zero delayElements: `Flux.just(1, 2, 3).delayElements(Duration.ZERO)` still doesn't cause the test to fail